# all test cases fail for hackerrank for python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, methods, logic

I have the following code where tasks were completed based on the exercise and certain steps were given to perform. Even though the output matches yet i get failed test case, not even one fulfills.

function call :stringmethod("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sem odio, varius nec aliquam nec, tempor commodo ante. Pellentesque sit amet augue vel ante dictum placerat ut ut sapien. Proin maximus eu diam in posuere. Suspendisse in lectus in lectus finibus auctor. Nam sed porttitor arcu. Vestibulum augue odio, posuere quis libero sed, pharetra sollicitudin est. Donec sit amet nunc eu nisi malesuada elementum id ut purus.Nunc sit amet % massa rhoncus, venenatis eros sit amet, ornare augue. Nunc a mi sed est tincidunt facilisis at nec diam. Donec nec ex lorem. Morbi vitae diam tincidunt, dignissim arcu ut, facilisis nisi. Maecenas non felis #ullamcorper, viverra augue id, consequat_nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Proin tempor, sapien ut ornare placerat, sapien mauris luctus sapien, eget aliquam turpis urna at quam. Sed a&eros vel@ ante vestibulum vulputate. Suspendisse vitae vulputate velit. Suspendisse! ligula nisl, semper ut sodales et, ultricies porttitor felis. Nunc ac mattis erat, aliquet pretium risus. Nullam quis congue lacus, et mollis nulla. Nunc laoreet in nisi sit amet facili*sis. Cras rutrum justo ut eros mollis volutpat. Sed quis mi nunc. Nunc sed bibendum nibh, quis bibendum tortor."
,"_!@*%#$.","3",
["adipiscing",
"Aliquam",
'Suspendisse',
'vulputate'], "vulputate")

```
from collections import Counter



def stringmethod(para, special1, special2, list1, strfind):
    # 1. remove all the special characters given in special1
    word1= ''.join([word for word in para if word not in special1])
    
    #2getting frst 70 and reversing from word1
    word2 = word1[:70]
    rword2= word2[::-1]
    print(rword2)
    
    #3.1removing white spaces from rword2
    rword2 = rword2.replace(" ","")
    #3.2joining the characters using special 2
    joint_string= special2.join(rword2)
    print(joint_string)
    
    #4. checking list1 with para 
    
    if (i in para for i in list1):
        print(f"Every string in {list1} were present")
    else:
        print(f"Every string in {list1} were not present")
        
    #5. splitting word from word1 and printing first 20 strings
    
    word1_split= word1.split()
    print(word1_split[:20])
    
    #frequency less than 2 using counter
    word_counter= Counter(word1_split)
    
    #making a temporary list to store split words for less than 3
    temp=[]
    for k,v in word_counter.items():
        if v<3:
            temp.append(k)
        else:
            pass
    #6. last 20 frequent words from temp
    last_20_words= temp[-20:]
    print(last_20_words)
    
    
    #7. print last index in word1 where substring strfind is found 
    
    print(word1.rfind(strfind))
```

raw input:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam sem odio, varius nec aliquam nec, tempor commodo ante. Pellentesque sit amet augue vel ante dictum placerat ut ut sapien. Proin maximus eu diam in posuere. Suspendisse in lectus in lectus finibus auctor. Nam sed porttitor arcu. Vestibulum augue odio, posuere quis libero sed, pharetra sollicitudin est. Donec sit amet nunc eu nisi malesuada elementum id ut purus.Nunc sit amet % massa rhoncus, venenatis eros sit amet, ornare augue. Nunc a mi sed est tincidunt facilisis at nec diam. Donec nec ex lorem. Morbi vitae diam tincidunt, dignissim arcu ut, facilisis nisi. Maecenas non felis #ullamcorper, viverra augue id, consequat_nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Proin tempor, sapien ut ornare placerat, sapien mauris luctus sapien, eget aliquam turpis urna at quam. Sed a&eros vel@ ante vestibulum vulputate. Suspendisse vitae vulputate velit. Suspendisse! ligula nisl, semper ut sodales et, ultricies porttitor felis. Nunc ac mattis erat, aliquet pretium risus. Nullam quis congue lacus, et mollis nulla. Nunc laoreet in nisi sit amet facili*sis. Cras rutrum justo ut eros mollis volutpat. Sed quis mi nunc. Nunc sed bibendum nibh, quis bibendum tortor.
,_!@*%#$.
,
3
adipiscing
Aliquam
Suspendisse
vulputate

[image]

Comment: What are the expected results? Also, could you provide a shorter and more understandable example?

Comment: Your function does not return anything. Are you sure hackerrank evaluates these tasks based on irrelvant side effects like prints to the console?

Comment: its the task to print the values. It passes the parameter in the backend and matches the result.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 : On the left hand panel you can see the expected output in the screenshot. The test cases match the output to the expected output. The below is expected result for three logics:                                                                                                         
ido mes mauqilA tile gnicsipida rutetcesnoc tema tis rolod muspi meroL
i,d,o,m,e,s,m,a,u,q,i,l,A,t,i,l,e,g,n,i,c,s,i,p,i,d,a,r,u,t,e,t,c,e,s,n,o,c,t,e,m,a,t,i,s,r,o,l,o,d,m,u,s,p,i,m,e,r,o,L
Every string in  ['adipiscing', 'Aliquam', 'Suspendisse'] were present